# React Route v6 - useRoutes index = true property?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

In this case, what is the puerpose of "index=true" ?
why do I use index=true ??
(react-router-dom v6 useRoutes)

```
{
      path: 'dashboard',
      element: (
        <AuthGuard>
          <DashboardLayout />
        </AuthGuard>
      ),
      children: [
           {
          path: 'e-commerce',
          children: [
            { element: <Navigate to="/dashboard/e-commerce/shop" replace />, index: true },
            { path: 'shop', element: <EcommerceShop /> },
            { path: 'product/', element: <EcommerceProductDetails /> },
            { path: 'list', element: <EcommerceProductList /> },
         
          ],
        },
```

Comment: You know, official documentation is usually a good source: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#index-routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`index` tells `react-router` that it should render the provided `element` when you are at the index of the `route`.

In this case it will render `<Navigate to="/dashboard/e-commerce/shop" replace />` at the `/dashboard/e-commerce` route. Which will in this case make sure that the user redirects to `/dashboard/e-commerce/shop` if they ever accidentally land on this route.

---

The concept behind an `index` route becomes more clear with an example:

```
<Route path="albums" element={<BaseLayout />}>
  <Route index element={<AlbumsList />} />
  <Route path=":id" element={<AlbumDetail />} />
  <Route path="new" element={<NewAlbumForm />} />
</Route>
```

At `/albums` it will render:

```
<BaseLayout>
  <AlbumsList />
</BaseLayout>
```

At `/albums/some-unique-album-id` it will render:

```
<BaseLayout>
  <AlbumDetail />
</BaseLayout>
```

At `/albums/new` it will render:

```
<BaseLayout>
  <NewAlbumForm />
</BaseLayout>
```