# Route Page is showing blank using Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am working with Reactjs and right now i am trying to use "dynamic routes",But page is showing blank,Here is my routes file

```
export default function Router() {
  return useRoutes([
     {       
     path: "/",
     element: <Layout />,
     errorElement: <Page404 />,
     children: [
        { element: <HomePage />, index: true },
        { element: <User />, index: true },
                ],     
        },  
        ]); 
}

const HomePage = Loadable(lazy(() => import("../pages/HomePage")));
const User = Loadable(lazy(() => import("../pages/User")));
const Page404 = Loadable(lazy(() => import("../pages/Page404")));
```

And i am trying to access "User.js" file inside (src/pages),Here is my User.js file

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams, withRouter } from "react-router";
import axios from "axios";
const User = (props) => {
    const params = useParams();
    const [users, setUsers] = useState({});
    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            const res = await axios(
                `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/${params.id}`
            );
            console.log("INDI", res.data);
            setUsers(res.data);
        }
        fetchData();
    }, []);
    return (
        <>
        <div>Hello worldddddddd</div>
        </>
    );
};

export default User;
```

Comment: You cannot have 2 index files, you user component must have a route path like `/user`

Comment: @DevMan not understand, if possible for you then please update my code so i can check

Comment: There can be only one index route per set of routes, you've incorrectly specified two so only the first is accessible. Give the second route an actual `path`. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you have added `index=true` for two children. You can have only one index page

Example :

```
return useRoutes([
   {       
   path: "/",
   element: <Layout />,
   errorElement: <Page404 />,
   children: [
      { element: <HomePage />, index: true },
      { element: <User />},
              ],     
      },  
      ]); 
}

const HomePage = Loadable(lazy(() => import("../pages/HomePage")));
const User = Loadable(lazy(() => import("../pages/User")));
const Page404 = Loadable(lazy(() => import("../pages/Page404")));
```

You can read more about what is the purpose of `index=true` from [this question accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72113415/react-route-v6-useroutes-index-true-property)